# Connect Mongo DB with Android application

Tags: java, android, mongodb

I'm trying to build android application to connect to MongoDB. Stuck to this problem.

MongoDB is accessible and without security. It is possible to add data with Mono Explorer from phone.

```
 public void sendMessage(View view) throws UnknownHostException {

    /**** Connect to MongoDB ****/
    // Since 2.10.0, uses MongoClient
    MongoClient mongo = new MongoClient("<MY IP>", 27017);

    /**** Get database ****/

    DB db = mongo.getDB("test");

    DBCollection table = db.getCollection("test");

    BasicDBObject document = new BasicDBObject();
    document.put("name", "mkyong");
    document.put("age", 30);
    document.put("createdDate", new Date(0));

    try {
            table.insert(document); 
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("unable to connect to MongoDB " + table.getFullName(), e);
        }
}
```

LOG:

```
11-04 19:01:56.825: E/dalvikvm(4448): Could not find class 'javax.management.ObjectName', referenced from method com.mongodb.util.management.jmx.JMXMBeanServer.createObjectName
11-04 19:01:57.095: E/AndroidRuntime(4448): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-04 19:01:57.095: E/AndroidRuntime(4448): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
11-04 19:01:57.095: E/AndroidRuntime(4448):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3691)
11-04 19:01:57.095: E/AndroidRuntime(4448):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4211)
11-04 19:01:57.095: E/AndroidRuntime(4448):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17267)
11-04 19:01:57.095: E/AndroidRuntime(4448):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
11-04 19:01:57.095: E/AndroidRuntime(4448):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-04 19:01:57.095: E/AndroidRuntime(4448):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-04 19:01:57.095: E/AndroidRuntime(4448):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
11-04 19:01:57.095: E/AndroidRuntime(4448):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-04 19:01:57.095: E/AndroidRuntime(4448):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-04 19:01:57.095: E/AndroidRuntime(4448):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
11-04 19:01:57.095: E/AndroidRuntime(4448):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
11-04 19:01:57.095: E/AndroidRuntime(4448):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-04 19:01:57.095: E/AndroidRuntime(4448): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
11-04 19:01:57.095: E/AndroidRuntime(4448):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-04 19:01:57.095: E/AndroidRuntime(4448):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-04 19:01:57.095: E/AndroidRuntime(4448):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3686)
11-04 19:01:57.095: E/AndroidRuntime(4448):     ... 11 more
11-04 19:01:57.095: E/AndroidRuntime(4448): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: _out shouldn't be null
11-04 19:01:57.095: E/AndroidRuntime(4448):     at com.mongodb.DBPort.go(DBPort.java:110)
11-04 19:01:57.095: E/AndroidRuntime(4448):     at com.mongodb.DBPort.call(DBPort.java:74)
11-04 19:01:57.095: E/AndroidRuntime(4448):     at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.innerCall(DBTCPConnector.java:286)
11-04 19:01:57.095: E/AndroidRuntime(4448):     at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.call(DBTCPConnector.java:257)
11-04 19:01:57.095: E/AndroidRuntime(4448):     at com.mongodb.DBApiLayer$MyCollection.__find(DBApiLayer.java:310)
11-04 19:01:57.095: E/AndroidRuntime(4448):     at com.mongodb.DB.command(DB.java:274)
11-04 19:01:57.095: E/AndroidRuntime(4448):     at com.mongodb.DB.command(DB.java:256)
11-04 19:01:57.095: E/AndroidRuntime(4448):     at com.mongodb.DB.command(DB.java:313)
11-04 19:01:57.095: E/AndroidRuntime(4448):     at com.mongodb.Mongo.getDatabaseNames(Mongo.java:393)
11-04 19:01:57.095: E/AndroidRuntime(4448):     at com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity.sendMessage(MainActivity.java:48)
11-04 19:01:57.095: E/AndroidRuntime(4448):     ... 14 more
```

Comment: What's your question? You're trying to use the Java MongoDB driver on Android?

Comment: Which line is throwing the exception?

Comment: The main error is that `javax.management.ObjectName` is not found. This is being called from mongo.jar, `com.mongodb.util.management.jmx.JMXMBeanServer.createObjectName`.

Comment: @Ted, have you found the solution yet as to where to get this javax library? And, I'm pretty sure mongo.jar is referencing a few other libraries I've found when I took apart the jar and tried to use it that way...